# Incorrect 'No space left on device' on Ubuntu and NTFS for rare directories and filenames

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, filesystems, ntfs-3g

I am experiencing the weirdest problem on a Ubuntu machine (fairly old Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS which for some reasons I am not ready to upgrade) and on an external USB drive NTFS formatted. Please notice that the machine has been up for years as a file and web server and there are no evident defects, despite pretty heavy usage, besides the ones discussed below. Since I have spent several hours to try to understand the problem without any success, I hope someone can give some hints on what could be happening (besides suggesting to move to a more recent version of Ubuntu--which I will do anyway but I cannot do now).

Here is an example of something which does not work ("/media/paolo\'s\ #3" is the USB-mounted device in question, of course):

```
rm -rf /media/paolo\'s\ #3/audio
id3v2 --list "/media/paolo's #3/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3"
    id3v2 tag info for /media/paolo's #3/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3:
    TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965)
    TCOM (Composer): Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)
    [...]
mkdir -p "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop"
cp "/media/paolo's #3/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3" "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop"
    cp: cannot create regular file `/media/paolo\'s #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3': No space left on device
```

That is, I simply want to create recursively a deep path and copy there a valid file from the root of the device. Of course, the problem is that there is plenty of space free on the disk (100s of GB).

Now, it is important to mention that I cannot simplify the paths because practically any other name would work fine. More specifically, I discovered the problem while running a Perl script which copies some GB of data and, out of thousands of directories similar to the above one, only a dozen have the problem (shown here escaped as if they were to be used in single quotes in the shell):

```
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bach, Carl Philipp Emanuel (1714-1788)/5. Opera/Oratorio '\''Die Auferstehung und Himmelfahrt Jesu'\'' for 3 Soli, SATB Chorus, and Orchestra, Wq240 (1777-1778) --  Schlick, Prégardien, Varcoe, Rheinische Kantorei, Das Kleine Konzert, Max
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bach, Johann Sebastian (1685-1750)/4. Vocal/Cantata no. 211 '\''Schweigt stille, plaudert nicht'\'' for Soprano, Tenor, Bass, Choir, and Orchestra, BWV211 (1734-1735) -- Hansmann, Equiluz, van Egmond, Concentus Musicus Wien, Harnoncourt
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bruhns, Nicolaus (1665-1697)/4. Vocal/Cantate '\''Muss nicht der Mensch'\'', for Soprano, Alto, Tenor, Bass, 2 Trumpets, Bassoon, 2 Violins, 2 Gambas, Cello, and Continuo -- De Reyghere, Bowman, De Mey, van Egmond, Ricercar Consort
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Caresana, Cristofaro (c1640-1709)/4. Vocal/Cantata '\''L'\''adoratione de'\'' Maggi'\'' for 6 Voices and Instruments '\''Per la nascita di nostro Signore'\'' (1676) -- Schiavo, Varriale, Mineccia, De Vittorio, Totaro, Naviglio, I Turchini, Florio
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Fux, Johann (1660-1741)/1. Orchestral/Serenada à 8 for 2 Trumpets, 2 Oboes, Bassoon, 2 Violins, Viola, and Continuo in C major from '\''Concentus musico-instrumentalis'\'', op. 1, K.352 (1701) -- Concentus Musicus Wien, Harnoncourt
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Handel, George Frideric (1685-1759)/4. Vocal/Motet '\''Saeviat tellus inter rigoris'\'' for Soprano, 2 Oboes, Strings, and Continuo in D major, HWV240 (1707) -- Massis, Choeur des Musiciens du Louvre, Les Musiciens du Louvre, Minkowski
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Schumann, Robert (1810-1856)/4. Vocal/Requiem for Mignon from Goethe'\''s '\''Wilhelm Meister'\'', op. 98b (1849) -- Bonney, Poschner, Schaechter, Hintermeier, Pita, Schmidt, Wiener Staatsopernchor, Chamber Orchestra of Europe, Abbado
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Telemann, Georg Philipp (1681-1767)/4. Vocal/Cantata '\''Ein Mensch ist in seinem Leben wie Gras'\'' for Soli ATB, Choir SATB, and Orchestra, TWV4&colon;18 -- Wessel, Jochens, Schreckenberger, Rheinische Kantorei, Das Kleine Konzert, Max
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Telemann, Georg Philipp (1681-1767)/5. Opera/Oratorio '\''Betrachtung der 9. Stunde an dem Todestage Jesu'\'' for Soli ATBB, Choir SATB, and Orchestra, TWV5&colon;5 -- Chordier, Jochens, Wimmer, van der Kamp, Rheinische Kantorei, Das Kleine Konzert, Max
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Verdi, Giuseppe (1813-1901)/4. Vocal/Messa da Requiem for 4 Solo Voices, Chorus, and Orchestra (1874) -- Tomowa-Sintow, Baltsa, Carreras, van Dam, Konzertvereinigung Wiener Staatsopernchor, Wiener Philharmoniker, von Karajan
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Waxman, Franz (1906-1967)/5. Opera/Joshua, Dramatic Oratorio for Soloists, Narrator, Mixed Chorus, and Orchestra (1959) -- Schnell, Gilfry, Hallenberg, Buchi, Poole, Prague Philharmonic Choir, Prague Philharmonia, Sedares
/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Zelenka, Jan Dismas (1679-1745)/4. Vocal/Missa Divi Xaverii, for Soloists SATB, Choir SATB, 2 Flutes, 2 Oboes, 4 Trumpets, Timpani, Strings, and Continuo in D major, ZWV12 (1729) -- Collegium Vocale 1704, Collegium 1704, Luks
```

A few comments about what I thought could be a cause of failure and, I believe, is not: (1) Neither of these paths, even including the name of the files to be copied therein are the longest I copy--there are much longer ones which works perfectly fine. (2) Although many of these contain UTF-8 non-ASCII characters and mildly special characters such as single quotes, most of the other successfully created directories and files have exactly the same characteristics. (3) Minor changes in the directory names may result in the process to succeed; in the first case of the list above, I noticed that removing one of the two spaces in front of "Schlick" results in success but adding a third one still fails. Again, please note that thousands of apparently very similar directories have no problem whatsoever. (4) After the first failed copy (due to a 'No space left on device'), further copy attempts (of the same or of other files) actually fail due to a 'Input/output error'. I am not sure if it matters, but dmesg does not seem to show absolutely anything related to this. (5) The behaviour is pretty deterministic and I observed it for the same directories for more than a week and has survived unmounting and remounting the USB disk many times.

To show the point (2) above, here is a working example:

```
rm -rf /media/paolo\'s\ #3/audio
mkdir -p "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bach, Johann Sebastian (1685-1750)/4. Vocal/Cantata no.  17 'Wer Dank opfert, der preiset mich' for Soprano, Alto, Tenor, Bass, Choir, and Orchestra, BWV17 (1726) -- Soloist of the Wiener Sängerknaben, Esswood, Equiluz, van Egmond, Wiener Sängerknaben, Concentus Musicus Wien, Harnoncourt"
cp "./mp3/Classical/Bach, Johann Sebastian (1685-1750)/4. Vocal/Cantata no.  17 'Wer Dank opfert, der preiset mich' for Soprano, Alto, Tenor, Bass, Choir, and Orchestra, BWV17 (1726) -- Soloist of the Wiener Sängerknaben, Esswood, Equiluz, van Egmond, Wiener Sängerknaben, Concentus Musicus Wien, Harnoncourt/01 -- Coro; Wer Dank opfert, der preiset mich.mp3" "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bach, Johann Sebastian (1685-1750)/4. Vocal/Cantata no.  17 'Wer Dank opfert, der preiset mich' for Soprano, Alto, Tenor, Bass, Choir, and Orchestra, BWV17 (1726) -- Soloist of the Wiener Sängerknaben, Esswood, Equiluz, van Egmond, Wiener Sängerknaben, Concentus Musicus Wien, Harnoncourt"
```

One can notice that here there are accented letters, double spaces, and that the overall path name of the first file copied therein is longer here than it is for one of the failing directories:

```
echo "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3" | wc -c
    303
echo "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bach, Johann Sebastian (1685-1750)/4. Vocal/Cantata no.  17 'Wer Dank opfert, der preiset mich' for Soprano, Alto, Tenor, Bass, Choir, and Orchestra, BWV17 (1726) -- Soloist of the Wiener Sängerknaben, Esswood, Equiluz, van Egmond, Wiener Sängerknaben, Concentus Musicus Wien, Harnoncourt/01 -- Coro; Wer Dank opfert, der preiset mich.mp3" | wc -c
    379
```

Here is another weird example of what happens. This actually works fine:

```
rm -rf /media/paolo\'s\ #3/audio
mkdir -p "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop"
touch "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop/TEST"
cp "/media/paolo's #3/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3" "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop"
id3v2 --list "/media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3" 
    id3v2 tag info for /media/paolo's #3/audio/mp3/Classical/Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)/4. Vocal/Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965) -- Kelly, Franklin-Kitchen, Nayeler, Budd, Charrier, Bournemouth Symphony Chorus and Orchestra, Alsop/01 -- Psalm 108 vs. 2 - Psalm 100.mp3:
    TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Chichester Psalms, for Boy Soprano, Mixed Chorus, Organ, Harp, and Percussion (1965)
    TCOM (Composer): Bernstein, Leonard (1918-1990)
    [...]
```

The only difference with the first example is that, before doing the copy, I touch a random file in the directory. Then, the copy works and (not shown in the example above) I can remove the touched file with everything remaining healthy. But if I immediately remove the file TEST after touching it, then the subsequent copy fails. Note that I was trying to use this technique to have a quick workaround in my script: while it worked fine on simple testcases, it fails working everywhere--alas, I have not much more information at this point.

I have no clue of what is going on and what I could do (again, short of changing Ubuntu version) to circumvent the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that these contain nonprinting characters that are not allowed? You mentioned deleting a "space" and the problem was resolved for that file but adding another space didn't fix it... is it possible the space you deleted wasn't actually a `space` (ansi 32) at all? It would also explain the last weird case and why other _apparently_ similar paths work fine.

If so you could regex replace all characters except word/allowed-symbol 
chars in each file/path name with a single space in your script to create a destination path for use when performing the copy operation.

Comment: Cliff, excellent idea, thanks. Unfortunately I just checked and all spaces are regular ones. Besides, everything is UTF-8 compliant, so it should work also with non breakable spaces, etc., in my view. But, anyway, there was none in one of the culprits I just checked.

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971467/2625090. Your test filename '/media/paolo\'s #3/audio/mp3/...' is 303 chars long, so the ntfs backend might be throwing an exception for such a long path and Ubuntu probably just translates it as a "no space left" error.

Comment: @arielnmz: I do not think it is a length problem, because I have many longer path names which work perfectly fine. They are both longer in total (see the 379 in the example above, which has no problem) and the longest component of the path (see the example above, although it is less clear to see immediately). No, I do not think length can be the problem--it was my first assumption because I always had problems of the sort in the past.

Comment: Maybe just an unrelated error that's being translated as a no-space-left error.

Comment: @arielnmz: Perhaps, but I would not know which kind of error, since it is a deterministic behaviour when I run the examples above and both the directories and files to be created are legitimate (as the workaround with touch confirms).

Comment: Have you tried copying with the cache/buffer disabled? or a sync'ed copy? rsync?